# Error:Project :app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, build.gradle, react-native-navigation

I am working with [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation), but not able to configure it in Android Studio as per the Given [documentation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android). Android Studio was given

Error:

> Error: Project: app declares a dependency from configuration 'compile' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :react-native-navigation.

My **React Native Version is : 0.50.3** and **npm version is :5.4.2**.

Steps that I followed are.

1. Create React Native Project.
2. Go inside the Project folder.
3. Run npm install --save react-native-navigation.
4. Open Android project(inside the react native project) into the android studio.
5. copy the code given code into settings.gradle

   include ':react-native-navigation'
    project(':react-native-navigation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-navigation/android/app/')

6.Copy the given code inside build.gradle(app)

```
compile project(':react-native-navigation')
```

So I am getting this error in the final step.

Please let me know if any quick fix is there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Comment: @sathyabaman no i didn't, i dropped that project and created the other one, it worked in the new project

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I was getting the same error. My situation was, I tried to create a separate native Android Library and tried to link it with the reactive project.

This issue comes when I run **react-native run-android** or **npm run android**. We are pretty sure, the issue occurs during the android build.

Solution what I tried was. I build my new android library and the android package using the android studio. Then I run the **react-native run-android** command in root react-native project folder.

It worked for me...